# Почему выходит ошибка: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python

```
chat_id = message.chat.id
code2 = ''
for i in range(5):
    code2 += chat_id[i]
```

Почему выходит ошибка: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Comment: мне кажется, код ошибки говорит сам за себя - вы пытаетесь взять индекс от целого числа. что вы хотите добиться в результате?

Comment: Хочу чтобы в code2 появились первые 5 чисел из chat_id

Comment: если `цифр`, а не `чисел`, то `str(chat_id)[:5]`